# How to make a label in c# dim on and off

Tags: c#

I want to display a message to web application users.

saying "Wait.. we are processing your reports"

so it appears then fade off repeatedly.

here is my label

```
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWait" Text="Wait.. we are analysing your reports." Font-Bold="true" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Can do that with CSS, take a look for "CSS animate opacity"

Comment: The easiest way would be not using a label, but an image (and animated gif with the fading effect)

Comment: please add the tag for the appropriate UI technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some Javascript. A good start for text fading using jquery would be this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

You will probably have to show the web page, then load the data separately using Ajax and Json.

Comment: A bit overkill imho, with css and a timer you can chain a [fade in and a fade out](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fading_buttons.asp)

Comment: @Cleptus How would this be achieved with CSS to indicate we are waiting for data and stop when done?

Comment: Hard to provide details, OP provides no info on how that reporting is done. Is it loaded asyncronously? If so, javascript should be used to hide the label/div when the data is shown. Is the full page reloaded when the report is finished? If so no need to do anything.